# Administrative Impersonation during Alchemy Installation

Tags: a4t

I just finished installing the Alchemy.

In one of the steps of installation wizard, it asks for the optional Windows Admin user information mentioning its not required for core functionality but some advance features utilize this and those features will be disabled.

[image]

What are those features?

Is there a way I can enable them later by adding Administrative Impersonation information or I just need to re-install the Alchemy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly which features are effected by this since it's on a per-plugin basis. Many plugins work without this, but some, such as servicer require the impersonation to function correctly. I would expect this kind of information to be listed under the release notes for individual plugins.

As for where you can update this information post-install, these are stored in the "impersonation" node of the Alchemy.xml file found at:

[Tridion Home]\web\Alchemy\Configuration\

Comment: Exactly right Tanner! Originally (pre-0.4.2) impersonation was required to install plugins, but as of 0.4.2 the only thing that's actually using impersonation is the Servicer plugin (as it needs Admin rights to perform IIS Recycles, COM+ Restarts, and Tridion Service Restarts).  

There'll most likely be advanced plugin types in the future that will require impersonation, the framework will most likely have an option to auto-impersonate or to prompt the user for credentials if impersonation is not set (features/functionality still under discussion).

Comment: For Tridion actions, you'll be able to use the "privilege elevation" feature of Web 8 - this won't work for Windows actions, but at least removes this requirement for Tridion actions.